# How to assign pandas.Series label/header to variable?

Tags: python, pandas

I'm a beginning Python programmer, so my knowledge is not very broad at all.

I had to count specific movie genres from a csv file and I tried to do it using pandas, since that was a solution Google offered me and it sounded interesting. This is my code:

```
final_lst = list(chain.from_iterable(all_c))
my_count = pd.Series(final_lst).value_counts()
print(my_count)
```

and this is my output:

```
[International Movies]            1927
[Dramas]                          1623
[Comedies]                        1113
[International TV Shows]          1001
[Documentaries]                    668
--> and so forth
```

I want to assign [International Movies] to a variable, so the genre name and **NOT** the integer value. How do I do this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow! Your question is not clear. A pandas series has three attributes that _may_ be what you're talking about, `my_count.name`, `my_count.index`,`my_count.values`. If you [edit] your question to provide a [mcve] with the actual result of `print(my_count)` and what exactly you're trying to do with that object, we may be able to help you better

Comment: I tried to clarify it a bit more. Hopefully, this is what you meant. Sorry if I still did it not right, I'm also new to stack overflow.

Comment: thank you for clarifying, that was very helpful! So given what you described, you can access the index values (genres) with `my_count.index`. So in this case, what about something like `my_var=my_count.index[0]`?

Answer (score 0):

You cab try this:

```
import pandas as pd
s = pd.Series([1, 2, 3], index=['A', 'B', 'C'])
```

Result:

```
A    1
B    2
C    3
```

And then:

```
list(s.index)
```

Result:

```
['A', 'B', 'C']
```